# What is the real working method of making a bootable usb drive?

Tags: terminal, usb, disk-utility, bootable-disk

Always when I need to make a bootable usb drive on a mac I struggle, I end up switching to windows because none of the below works for me, I'm using MacBook Pro:

- running `sudo dd if=Debian.is of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=512k` in terminal
- using Disk Utility, formatting the usb to have 1 partition, MBR and unmounting the partition, then dragging the iso image onto restore tab
- using `diskutils` for the above

On Windows we have plenty of tools. I always struggle with creating either Ubuntu bootable  usb stick or Windows 7 in the company deployment process.

Answer (score 2):

a) You can use the free and open source [Mac Linux USB Loader](http://sevenbits.github.io/Mac-Linux-USB-Loader/) app to make a bootable USB drive.

OR

b) Follow the instructions for [How to create a bootable USB stick on OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) (it has a step to convert ISO files to IMG before writing it to the USB drive).

Comment: The method outlined in the ubuntu wiki has always worked for me.

Comment: Will it work for creating bootable Windows 7 Installation usb drives as well ?

Answer (score 1):

[How To Make A Live Linux USB On A Mac](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KRG6RiKBMFk) will guide you visually through the process.

Its [official website](http://penguintosh.com/) can also be seen for step by step guidance.